# Iterate in reverse in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate a list in reverse in Thymeleaf, but the th:each iteration only seems to go forward. My array is sorted from least to greatest, and I would like to create DOM objects in greatest to least. Here is what I have:

```
<li th:each="option : ${upgradeOptions}">
  <div class="billing__product-option">
    <div class="billing__product-duration" th:text="${...}">3 months</div>
    <div class="billing__payment-subtotal" th:text="${...}">$25</div>
    <div class="billing__payment-monthly-charge" th:text="${...} + tax')">$25</div>
    <div class="billing__payment-discount""></div>
    <input class="billing__button" type="button" value="Select" />
  </div>
</li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sort the array from greatest to least?

Comment: I was hoping to not have to touch the backend. The object containing the collection only exposed an iterator. I think this may have been too specific of a question.